# How to link libs in CLion?

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen, clion

I'm using CLion as my IDE for C++ development and I'm trying to get Eigen included.

How do I do this?
I've downloaded and unzipped Eigen and placed it in C:/ (Which I've read online is the path where CMake looks for libs when you use **find_library()**)

In the **CMakeLists.txt** I've added

```
find_library(Eigen3 3.4 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
add_executable(Lecture03 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (Lecture03 Eigen3::Eigen)
```

But then it can't find Eigen, I get the following error when reloading my **CMakeLists**:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_library):
Could not find Eigen3 using the following names: 3.4
```

My question is, what did I do wrong? Did I place the Eigen folder in the wrong directory? Can I change where CMake looks for libs in CLion?

Comment: Smells like you wanted to use `find_package` instead of `find_library`.

Comment: If I do that, I get this error: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" (requested
  version 3.4) with any of the following names:

    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.

Comment: That error explicitly tells what to do: "Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH". Have you tried to set that environment variable?

Comment: "... and placed it in C:/ (Which I've read online is the path where CMake looks for libs when you use `find_library()`) - No, by default CMake doesn't treat `C:/` as an installation prefix and does not search under it.

Comment: I've tried doing it in the settings for CMake in CLion, then I get this error:
ninja: error: build.ninja:35: loading 'CMakeFiles/rules.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified.

include CMakeFiles/rules.ninja
                              ^ near here

Comment: Probably, you have done something wrong. Please, update the **question post** with your code, which uses `find_package`, with description of settings CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH you have made and with the error message it causes.

Comment: "I've downloaded and unzipped Eigen" Although Eigen is a header only library it seems you need to **build** and **install** Eigen to use `find_package` and the CMake config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being to use

```
include_directories(C:/CPP_Libs/Eigen3)
```

in my CMakeLists.txt, and

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
```

in whichever file needs it

Answer (score 0):

Eigen (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is a template library. That means it is header only, there is nothing to link against.

For CMake that means you can use `find_path` to find the header file